# Why doesn't this file allow me to access archie via the internet?

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, nginx

I'm trying to set up nginx on an RPi to act as a web server, a nextcloud server, and a reverse proxy server.  Currently I'm 0 for 3 but this question is about the reverse proxy server.   Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file.  The /archie proxypass works if I try to access it via a computer on the same LAN, but I want it to be available via the internet (ideally without having to forward a port on my router, because I'm running out of slots).

My IP address is dynamic, just to make things slightly more fun.

Does anyone have any ideas please?  Be gentle; this is my first foray into this sort of thing!

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jonbray.uk.to;

    location /nextcloud {
        proxy_pass http://localhost/nextcloud;
    }

    location /archie {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.2:80;
    }

    location /minibeast {
       rewrite ^/minibeast(.*)$ $scheme://192.168.0.3$1 permanent;
    }


    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
}
```

Comment: What kind of failures are you seeing? What actually happens when you visit `/archie`, according to your browser (address bar, DevTools network tab) – do you stay at `jonbray.uk.to/archie` or does the webapp attempt to redirect you to `http://192.something`?